# Ways to share DTO across microservices?

Tags: architecture, microservices, architectural-patterns, dto, pubsub

I am designing a system to receive data from various types of sensors, and convert and then persist it to be used by various front-end and analytics services later.

I'm trying to design every service to be as independent as possible, but I'm having some trouble. The team has decided on a DTO we would like to use. The outward-facing services (sensor data recipients) will receive the data in their own unique way, then convert it to a JSON object (the DTO) and send it off to the Message Broker. Consumers of the messages will then know exactly how to read the sensor data messages.

The problem is that I'm using the same DTO in a few different services. An update has to be implemented in multiple locations. Obviously, we've designed it in such a way that a few extra or missing fields in the DTO here and there are not much of an issue until the services have been updated, but it's still bugging me and makes me feel like I'm making a mistake. It could easily turn into a headache.

Am I going about architecting the system wrong? If not, what are some ways around this, or at least to ease my worries?

Comment: What kind of DTOs are you sharing, and what protocol are you using between services? It's okay to share, for instance, the `proto` file for gRPC or the `avro` schema for Kafka and generate the DTOs in both services, but I wouldn't share a shared library between two projects.

Comment: Encoded JSON strings and AMQP. I would prefer not to use anything language-specific.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

My advice? **Do not share** these DTOs among the applications in any kind of library. Or at least don't do this right now.

I know, seems very counter-intuitive. You are duplicating code, right? But this is not a business rule, so you can be more flexible.

The service that sends the DTO needs to be rigid in his message contract, like an Rest API. The service can't change the DTO in a way that could break the other services that are already consuming the information from the DTO.

When a new field is added do DTO, you only update the other services that consume this DTO **if** they need the new field. Otherwise, forget it. Using JSON as content-type you have the flexibility to create and send new attributes without breaks the code of the services that don't map these new fields on his actual versions of DTO.

But if this situation is really bothering you, you can follow the [Rule of Three](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-delusion-of-reuse/):

> There are two "Rules of Three" in reuse: (a) It is three times as
>   difficult to build reusable components as single use components, and
>   (b) a reusable component should be tried out in three different
>   applications before it will be sufficiently general to accept into a
>   reuse library.

So, try to wait a bit more before sharing this DTO among the services.

Comment: Very much appreciated. This is really one of very few major concerns I have going forward. Not enough to keep me up at night, but enough to worry me.

Comment: Duplicated DTOs (in different and very independent services) don't violate DRY. That's it.

Comment: Presumably then there's no reason not to copy the DTO source code directly from one project to another, as a one-off operation, although then any parts not required in the new project should probably be deleted.

Comment: Even a whole service might be delete causing no major problems to the whole system. Ideally.

Comment: To clarify the essence of the answer, when developing microservices, each service should be developed as if they do not know about the other services, except for the actual contracts it may require.

Comment: What about DTO-Entity mappers? Can't it be shared? DTO's can be automated by generating from the code generator using spec but mappers can't be. So what is the suggested approach?

Comment: What if among the DTOs there are a few enum classes? Some of the enums can be extremely general purpose, properly named and with comments. Duplicating all that work across multiple projects seems like a DRY violation to me. If the enumeration is stable enough, it should be shared some way, shouldn't it? Suppose for example there is a `CountryCode` enum, with every country code for all current countries in the world. Would it be wise to duplicate this too?

Comment: @julealgon a `CountryCode` is not something that are changed with much frequency, so it's not really a problem to have this as a shared library or even duplicated among the services, because will not make much difference for most cases.

Comment: @Ayyappa can you elaborate more your question? My understanding of "DTO-Entity mapper" is libraries like MapStruct (for Java).

Answer (score 20):

When it comes to Microservices, services' [development life cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) should be independent too.<sup>*</sup>

### Different SLDC and different dev teams

in a real MS system, there could be several teams involved in the development of the ecosystem, each of which in charge of one or more services. In turn, these teams might be located in different offices, cities, countries, plan... Perhaps, they don't even know each other, what makes sharing knowledge or code very hard (if possible). But this could be very convenient because shared code also implies a sort of sharing reasoning and something important to recall is that, whatever makes sense for a specific team, doesn't have to make it for another team. For example, given the DTO *Customer*, it could be different depending on the service in play, because *customers* are interpreted (or seen) differently from each service.

### Different needs, different technologies

Isolated SLDCs also allows teams to choose the stack that best suits their needs. Imposing DTOs implemented in a specific technology limits the capacity of the teams to choose.

### DTOs are neither business rules nor services contracts

What DTOs are really? Plain objects with no other goal than moving data from one side to another. Bags of getters and setters. It's not the kind of "knowledge" that worth reuse, overall because there's no knowledge at all. Their volatility also makes them bad candidates for coupling.

Contrary to what Dherik has stated, it **must** be possible for a service to change its DTOs without having to make other services to change at the same time. Services **should** be **tolerant readers, tolerant writers and fail tolerant**. Otherwise, they cause coupling in such a way that makes the service architecture a no sense. Once more, and contrary to Dherik's answer, if three services need exactly the very same DTOs, it's likely something went wrong during the services decomposition.

### Different business, different interpretations

While there could be (and there will be) cross-cutting concepts among services, it does not mean we have to impose a  canonical model to force all services to interpret them in the same way.

#### Case study

Say our company has three departments, *Customer Service*, *Sales* and *Shipping*. Say each of these releases one or more services.

Customer Service,  due to its *[domain language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)*, implements services around the concept of customers, where *customers* are *persons*. For instance, *customers* are modeled as *name*, *last name*, *age*, *gender*, *email*, *phone*, etc.

Now say, *Sales* and *Shipping* model their services according to their respective domain languages as well. In these languages, the concept *customer* appears too but with a subtle difference. To them, *customers*  are not (necessarily) *persons*.  For   *Sales*, customers are a *Document number* a *Credit Card* and a *billing address*,  for *Shipping* a *full name* and a *shipping address* too.

If we force *Sales* and *Shipping* to adopt the canonical data model of *Customer Service*, we are forcing them to deal with unnecessary data that could end up introducing unnecessary complexity if they have to maintain the whole representation and keep the *customer* data in sync with *customer service*.

**Related links**

- [Microservices & Canonical model](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335585/microservices-canonical-model)
- [Avoid a Canonical Data Model](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/04/canonical-data-models)

---

<sup>***** Here is where the strengths of this architecture lays on</sup>

Comment: Thank you! The case studies are actually what helped me determine whether to share DTOs or not. Now I am sure as to why I did not want to share them.

Comment: "if three services need exactly the very same DTOs, it's likely something went wrong during the services decomposition". I totally agree

Answer (score 16):

> I'm trying to design every service to be as independent as possible

You should be publishing *events*. Events are certain type of messages that represent *a solid fact* about something that has happened at a particular point in time.

Each service should have a very well defined responsibility, and should have the responsibility of publishing the events related to that responsibility.

Furthermore, you want your events to be represent business related events, not technical events. E.g. prefer `OrderCancelled` event to an `OrderUpdated` with `status: "CANCELLED"`.

That way, when a service needs to react to a cancelled order, it just needs to listen to a that particular type of message, which is carrying only data relevant to that event. E.g. an `OrderCancelled` probably just needs an `order_id`. Whichever service that needs to react to this has already stored whatever it needs to know about the order in its own data store.

But if the service only had `OrderUpdated` events to listen to, then it would need to interpret on the flow of events, and it was now dependent on delivery order to conclude correctly when an order was cancelled.

In your case, however, as your are publishing sensor data, it could make sense to have a service, listen to the events and publish a new stream of "business events", e.g. `TemperatureThresholdExceeded`, `TemperatureStabilised`.

And be careful about creating too many microservices. Microservices can be a great way of encapsulating complexity, but if you don't discover suitable service boundaries, your complexity is in the service integration. And that is a nightmare to maintain.

It's better to have too few, too large services, than to have too many, too small services.

Answer (score 0):

The most brought up reason for not sharing dtos is different  bounded context could have different interpretations. However there should only be a **single source of truth** which should hold data that contains every field needed to serve all its consumers. I would say if you want to share dtos, understanding what is a complete DTO (from business perspective) would be a prerequisite.

Another brought up reason is that services are no longer loosely coupled anymore, as a change triggered by one service forces a change in the other. I cannot imagine what type of change could trigger this. Deletion of fields should never be done as long as there are consumers using them. New fields can be ignored if the consumer is not interested. Also keep in mind that versioning of the library provides good flexibility because each service is free to choose its version of the DTO.